# Error with the less color variable values

Tags: css, html, less

I am just learning [less](http://lesscss.org/).I have my `html` file like this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-IN">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>.::LESS::.</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type=text/css"" href="style.less" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="less.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box1">This is box1</div>
  <div class="box2">This is box2</div>
  <div class="box3">This is box3</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my `style.less` file is like this

```
@blue : #00c;
@light-blue: @blue + #333;
@deep-blue: @blue - #333;
.box1 {
  background-color: @blue;
}
.box2 {
  background-color: @light-blue;
}
.box3 {
  background-color: @deep-blue;
}
```

But after all this when I am going to check the `html page from the browser` it is not showing anything.If I am `changing the values of background-color` to `any color values` then the background color can be seen over there.Can some one tell me where is the wrong part?Any help and suggestions will be welcome.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code compiles correctly to

```css
.box1 {
  background-color: #00c;
}
.box2 {
  background-color: #3333ff;
}
.box3 {
  background-color: #000099;
}
```

However, the following line you wrote:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type=text/css"" href="style.less" />
```

should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="style.less" />
```

Try this and check again if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an # for light blue. Is [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wrAcH) how it is supposed to look like?

Comment: I have made the necessary changes but still I am not getting any result.